# i tried to use sonarqube but failed to run it using maven command "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=token"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I used [sonarqube-spring boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQ7_pcaw-iM) video to learn sonarqube but failed. I had created token from sonarqube and tried "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=sqp_e1cf0bc2bf1ea3567f35f4667c2edd2ca37b4c78" from intellij. it shows error [Unknown lifecycle phase ".login=".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Bkf.png) . My Pom file plugins

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It looks like some spaces between "-D" and other parts ... "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=s..." please check your call...

Comment: i checked and found no space.

Comment: The error output implies something different...

Answer (score 0):

What if you run instead:

`mvn -Dsonar.token=your_token -Dsonar.url=sonar_url sonar:sonar`

?